# Unable to create an object of com components written in unmanaged code from .Net wcf service

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, com, wcf-client, apartments

I am writing a Wcf Service library and want to load an unmanaged com dll. The com dll threaded model is not set so its a Single-threaded legacy component that runs only in the main STA [threading model](http://www.thrysoee.dk/InsideCOM+/ch04d.htm)

In wcf service, I have set the apartment as STA [like](http://scottseely.com/2009/07/17/calling-an-sta-com-object-from-a-wcf-operation/)

Now when I try to create the instance of com component, it gives an exception

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException : External component has thrown an exception.
```

When I debug the com dll and it was throwing an error `RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD`.

I can fix the problem by setting threading model to `Free Threaded Marshaller`. But i am not allowed to change the current threading model of com dll.

So please help me that how can I access the com dll from wcf service?

.Net Framework 4.0, Windows 7 x64

Comment: infact i can access the COM dlls from a simple C# console application by setting the apartment as STA, because i am accessing it from main thread which matches the threading model of COM dlls.

Comment: but in wcf service i am trying to access the COM via worker thread (which is STA),so its not being accessed. so is there any way to access the COM from the main thread of WCF service????

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally the problem is resolved....

steps:

1. host the wcf service library into the WindowsForm App.
2. set the WindowsForm app's threading apartment to STA
3. set the dispatcher defined in the wcf service to the current dispatcher like

   WcfTest.Service1.disp = System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

and thats all :)